# Azure deployment error "Subscription is not registered with NRP"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-deployment, azure-subscription

Anyone faced this error before when running [az deployment mg create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/mg?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-mg-create) command to deploy a bicep file with parameters? I thought it was transient, but it happens consistently daily during my deployment testing.

Also raised this question [on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/10484).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Network` resource provider is not registered for the related subscription.
You can check the documentation to enable it:

[Register resource provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#register-resource-provider)

Comment: Is there an azure cli command that would allow one to do this?

Comment: It is in the article: `az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Network`

Comment: thanks and for those future readers who use Azure PowerShell, Register-AzResourceProvider cmdlet is what you can use

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting error while applying a blueprint:

```
There were error(s) encountered during the deployment:
The artifact 'network_deploy_spoke' of type 'Template' failed to deploy due to the following error: Template deployment failed with error [ 
{ "code": "SubscriptionNotRegistered", "message": "Subscription XXX is not registered with NRP." }, 
{ "code": "SubscriptionNotRegistered", "message": "Subscription XXX is not registered with NRP." }, 
{ "code": "SubscriptionNotRegistered", "message": "Subscription XXX is not registered with NRP." }, 
{ "code": "SubscriptionNotRegistered", "message": "Subscription XXX is not registered with NRP." } ]
```

So as methioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-powershell), used below to find and compare `NotRegistered` providers.

`Get-AzResourceProvider -ListAvailable | Where-Object RegistrationState -eq "NotRegistered" | Select-Object ProviderNamespace, RegistrationState | Sort-Object ProviderNamespace`

Then registering with those using below fixed the issue for me:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.KeyVault 
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Management
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.RecoveryServices
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Sql
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web
```